# Ember-data, hasMany relationship, loading sub-collection, nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, ember-data

I need to load a model from a rails backend with ember-data and its default REST adaptor. I have a model that has many relationship with another one :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("String");
    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment', {keys: 'post_ids', embbeded: true});
})

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    body: DS.attr("String");
    post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post');
})
```

The JSON model returned by the server looks like

```
{
  title: "a title",
  comment_ids: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

I need at first to load all the posts without necessarly loading the associated comments, for efficiency reason. I do this with

```
App.store.findAll('App.Post');
```

And, when I select a specific post I need to load all the comments. In the ember-data documentation, it's said that I just need to call

```
a_specific_post.get('comments')
```

When, I do this I get a very long url with all comment ids :

```
GET : /comments?ids%all_ids_appended_here
```

Of course it doesn't work and if I have a thousand of comment the url is very very long.

Is it possible to get a request that matches nested routing model of rails ? :

```
 GET /posts/post_id/comments
```

The plugin route-manager https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager seems to this kind of routing. Can I use it with ember-data and how ?

Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing thesame issue when using rails nested route with  ember-data. Did you solve this and can you post the solution and mark it as the accepted answer for the benefit of others. thanks

Comment: AFAIK nested resources are still not supported by ember-data. I guess one could instantiate individual adapters (maybe even stores have to be "duplicated") for each nested model and dynamically assign them baseURLs. I haven't tried this since it also looks like a bit of a long-shot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure embedded is what you want if you're only specifying comment IDs. It is expecting full comment objects to be passed in the JSON representation of the post model.